# Going through controls in order

Tags: vb.net

I'm creating an XML file with the text fields of a form. When I go through them using a `For Each` loop:

```
For each Ctrl in Me.Controls 
    'dosomething
Next
```

it doesn't take them in order; that is, it first takes the `TextBox` in the middle, then the first one, then another and it keeps going that way.

Is there a way where I can take the values in order?

Comment: Using the firs TextBox that appears in the form, then the secondone, from top to bottom.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Me.Controls` contains the controls in the order they were created.

To change that, select the first control (in the designer), click Send to Back, and repeat.

Comment: Yes, it worked, thankyou very much! You saved me from doing a function to save them in an array and then going through the array!

Comment: @carlos You can sort the controls without explicitly creating an array yourself. Use LINQ!  See Tim's answer below. One line of code.

Answer (score 8):

You could order by `TabIndex`:

```
Dim allTextBoxes = From txt In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
                   Order By txt.TabIndex
```

Another way is to order by the location:

```
allTextBoxes = From txt In Me.Controls.OfType(Of TextBox)()
               Order By txt.Location.Y, txt.Location.X


For Each txt In allTextBoxes
    '  ...
Next
```

Comment: @Slaks: What is _correct_? If it's not what OP requires, then maybe it's the order they appear on the form(the location, my second approach). If that's also not what he needs, he should either manually set the TabIndex correctly or recreate them in the order he want(your approach).

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you.  Not a VB guy but this is my attempt at ordering the controls by their location, top to bottom.

```
... Me.Controls.OrderBy(Function(c) c.Location.Y)
```