# How to change the order controls are read in .Net?

Tags: vb.net, forms, textbox

I have a very textbox rich heavy panel (approx ~ 25 textboxes) for which I want to retrieve all my text from.

I've done so using this loop.

```
Dim AllItemsArray As New ArrayList
For Each txt As Control In Panel2.Controls
        If txt.GetType Is GetType(TextBox) Then
            AllItemsArray.Add(txt.Text)
        End If
Next
```

However, for some odd reason it reads the textboxes in a completly random order which makes using the information extremely difficult.
I thought that the textboxes were read in the order they are made, but so far it hasn't done so.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can alter it so that it reads the textboxes in order?

IE. textbox1.text, textbox2.text ...etc

and not

textbox5.text, textbox2.text, textbox 20 ....etc

Thanks

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335529/going-through-controls-in-order) which should help order your `Controls`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gets the controls in Tab order sequence.  It also gets controls that are in containers, i.e. GroupBox.

```
    Dim ctrl As Control = Me.GetNextControl(ctrl, True)
    Do While ctrl IsNot Nothing
        Debug.WriteLine(ctrl.Name)

        ctrl = Me.GetNextControl(ctrl, True)
    Loop
```