# Public member 'Count' on type 'OrderedEnumerable(Of Panel,Integer)' not found

Tags: vb.net

I used a linq example from the link below.
[Going through controls in order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335529/going-through-controls-in-order)

This was exactly what I was looking for. It worked for me. Thank you Tim Schmelter

I added a timer control and some codes. My problem starts now. After that, while running it shows an error. 
Even if I remove the code areas using the count property, It won't work.

> Public member 'Count' on type 'OrderedEnumerable(Of Panel,Integer)' not found.

I have imported ...
Imports System.Linq

Can Anyone help me. I am new to vb.net

```
    Private Sub InitialisePanels() '(pnl As Control)
    Dim allPanels = From pnl In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Panel)()
               Order By pnl.TabIndex

    'Dim blnControlPresent As Boolean
    For Each pnl As Panel In allPanels
        If pnl.[GetType]().Name = "Panel" Then
            pnl.BringToFront()
            pnl.Visible = True
            pnl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            pnl.Visible = False
            pnl.SendToBack()
        End If
    Next
    If allPanels.Count > 0 Then
        allPanels(mFirstPanel).BringToFront()
        allPanels(mFirstPanel).Visible = True
        mCurrentPanel = mFirstPanel
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you Tim. But it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I must admit that i'm not sure what the problem is(apart from the fact that `allPanels(mFirstPanel)` doesn't compile because an `OrderedEnumerable` has no indexer), but this should work, presuming you want to bring the first panel to front:

```
Private Sub InitialisePanels() '(pnl As Control)
    Dim allPanels = From pnl In Me.Controls.OfType(Of Panel)()
                    Order By pnl.TabIndex    
    For Each pnl As Panel In allPanels
        pnl.BringToFront()
        pnl.Visible = True
        pnl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill
        pnl.Visible = False
        pnl.SendToBack()
    Next

    Dim firstPanel As Panel = allPanels.FirstOrDefault()

    If firstPanel IsNot Nothing Then
        firstPanel.BringToFront()
        firstPanel.Visible = True
        mCurrentPanel = firstPanel
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much Tim. It worked. It took some time to complete my coding. So was late to respond. Anyway, I have the doubt, why the count method didn't work. I couldn't figure it out.